# URLencoding with specific Charset

Tags: php, html, encoding, character-encoding, urlencode

When i try this link out "http://www.url-encode-decode.com/" which i use to encode using  GB2312, it returns `%D4%B2%CD%A8%CB%D9%B5%DD` *which is what i want*. But when i do a normal URL encoding in php using

```
$urlencoded = urlencode('圆通速递');
```

it returns

```
%E5%9C%86%E9%80%9A%E9%80%9F%E9%80%92
```

Doesnt turn out as what i want. How do i URL encode in a specific charset?

Comment: Convert from UTF-8 first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try converting the encoding of the string first. Something like this:

```
$urlencoded = urlencode(mb_convert_encoding('圆通速递','GB2312','UTF-8'));
```

Comment: I need %D4%B2%CD%A8%CB%D9%B5%DD as END result

Comment: As above returns %C3%A5%C2%9C%C2%86%C3%A9%C2%80%C2%9A%C3%A9%C2%80%C2%9F%C3%A9%C2%80%C2%92

Comment: I missed your specific charset, I've updated my question to match it - I think it returns what you are looking for now.

Comment: Oh god, i feel so stupid .... iconv failed on me. What's the difference between mb and iconv?

Comment: mb_* functions support multi-byte characters, like Japanese and Chinese characters

Comment: Thanks :) Been a stalker for a while and now saw an opportunity to contribute

Answer (score 1):

```
echo urlencode(mb_convert_encoding('圆通速递','GB2312',"auto"));
```

result:

%D4%B2%CD%A8%CB%D9%B5%DD

Comment: Hi @Dagon, Thank you! :) I really appreciate your reply :)